# A generic error occurred in GDI+ error when trying to save Bmp image

Tags: vb.net

I am facing some problems in my windows form, I am trying to save a BMP image but it generates the following exception. " A generic error occurred in the GDI+.

Here is my code:

```
public void SaveImage(String file)
    {          
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Width, Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, 0, Width, Height);

        panel1_Paint(null, new PaintEventArgs(g, this.ClientRectangle));

        bmp.Save(file);
    }
```

Comment: that is not VB code, but what is the purpose of `panel1_Paint` there and how does it relate to saving an image?

Comment: Dispose graphics before saving to file.

Comment: This can also happens if process that tries to save the file doesn't have access (file is locked or does not have write access).

Comment: thanks guys managed to solve it now.